# How to apply multiple events on single HTML text field?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I want to call a function through multiple events `onBlur`, `onKeyup` and `onClick` but my script is working only on first event.

**My Code :**

```
<input type="text" onBlur="getprice(this),getdesc(this)" onClick="getprice(this),getdesc(this)" id="item" name="item[]">
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: http://jsbin.com/zikagu/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" onBlur="getprice(this);getdesc(this)" onClick="getprice(this);getdesc(this);" id="item" name="item[]">
```

When you sign the function to an dom element inline, remember, inside the double quotation, you are writing javascript code. So for each function, should have a ';' as the end, happy coding bro!

Comment: I have some other issue in function, the event is working with both " ; " and  " , " but thanks for answering @kevin

Comment: @Arif, happy coding bro !

Comment: @KevinSimple I put one another question associated with the same feature, Can you please check that also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33799161/dynamically-added-text-field-have-default-value-of-first-text-field

Comment: @Arif, sure, I am checking on that

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the below code where I have defined the target events in `var events`. You can add multiple events there to add to your functionality.

You can check the output in your browser `Console`.

**Console Output**

```
__EVENT__ click
__getPrice__ Empty
__getDesc__ Description
__EVENT__ blur
__getPrice__ Ok
__getDesc__ Description
__EVENT__ click
__getPrice__ Ok
__getDesc__ Description
__EVENT__ click
__getPrice__ 9874521
__getDesc__ Description
__EVENT__ blur
__getPrice__ 9874521
__getDesc__ Description
```

**Code Snippet**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Attach Multiple Events</title>
  <style>
    input[type="text"] {
      border: none;
      outline: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="textInput" name="textInput[]" placeholder="Write your input...">
  <script>
    (function() {
      // Define variables
      var
        events = ['click', 'blur'],
        textInput = document.querySelector('#textInput');

      // Define functions
      var
        getPrice = function(textInputRef) {
          console.log('__getPrice__', textInputRef.value == '' ? 'Empty' : textInputRef.value);
        },
        getDesc = function(textInputRef) {
          console.log('__getDesc__', 'Description');
        };

      events.forEach(function(e) {
        textInput.addEventListener(e, function() {
          console.log('__EVENT__', e);
          getPrice(this);
          getDesc(this);
        }, false);
      });
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

To get more control over your `Events`, it's better to attach events to your target elements separately.

Just an advise! Do not write inline JavaScript in HTML. It is always better to write JavaScript separately (preferably in a **separate file**) for following reasons.

1. Reduce HTML file size
2. Support caching
3. Improve accessibility
4. Easy code maintenance

Hope it helps!

Comment: If you down vote any answer, have some **GUTS** to explain the reason for it as it is in everyone's interest. Thanks!