# Dynamically added text field have default value of first text field

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a script where I can add text fields with "Add Button" but the rest of fields get default value of first field. You can check the [demo here](http://graduzone.com/demo/). Just type Apple in item field in demo and you will get the price 69 for that. Then when you click "Add Item" button, it gives you default value of 69 for all generated price fields. I want to show the empty price field for new items.

My Script :

**Add Dynamic Row**

```
function addRow(tableID) {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
                //alert(newcell.childNodes);
                switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                    case "text":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                            break;
                    case "checkbox":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                            break;
                    case "select-one":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                            break;
                }
            $(function() {
              var availableTags = [
              "Apple",
              "Samsung",
              "Blackberry",
              "Nokia",
              ];
              $('input[name="item[]"]').autocomplete({
                  source: availableTags
              });
            });
            }
        }
```

**Get Item Price Script**

```
function getXMLHTTP() { //fuction to return the xml http object
        var xmlhttp=false;  
        try{
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch(e)    {       
            try{            
                xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e){
                try{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e1){
                    xmlhttp=false;
                }
            }
        }

        return xmlhttp;
    }
      function getproduct(element) {      

        var strURL="getProduct.php?product="+element.value; 
        var req = getXMLHTTP();

        if (req) {

            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {   
                        // last changes here:
                        element.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('productdiv')[0].innerHTML=req.responseText;                       
                    } else {
                        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }               
            }           
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }       
    }
```

**getProduct.php script :**

```
<?php 
$product = $_GET['product'];
if($product == "Apple") {
    $value = 69;
} else {
    $value = 59;
}
?>
<input name="unit_price[]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" onkeyup="getValues()" id="unit_price" placeholder="Price" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mate, you problem is at : newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;

you always assign the first row value to the new added item no matter how

Comment: so how can I change it, i tried different options but didn't worked out for me. Can you please check it

Comment: change  newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML; to  newcell.innerHTML = '', then it;s gonna be empty always. dont forget tick my answer bro ! lol

Comment: Kevin, I tried it but its not working. It doesn't even add new row with your code.

Comment: @Arif, can you open the browser console, see if any error? Also, can you create a jsfiddle, so I can fix on that? I dont have a local php environment

Comment: in console, it gives me error of "addRow is not defined". I'm making jsfiddle account and will let you know. My net is very slow and taking so much time.

Comment: @Arif, no problem, I am doing other coding now, so let me know once you have a jsfiddle, then I'll fix it

Comment: Can you please check jsfiddle now at http://jsfiddle.net/shams_okz/7fh1y1n4/ . I don't know how to use php code in jsfiddle?

Comment: check this, http://jsfiddle.net/xq8u5tcn/  , just reference your php url in the code, if you have a  public ip/server

Comment: this is my php page online graduzone.com/demo/getProduct.php and the code in that page is mentioned in my question above also. I tried different thing but didn't solve the issue. Please try it if you can?